# Warning: Undefined property: stdClass since php8.1

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8.1

Since update to php 8.1 I've the problem in a foreach that will give the below error.

> Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$1 in /ActivityShow.php on line 2271

line: 2271: is

```
<p style='color: #BD3A84; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 0px;'>" .
                $obj->locatie->{1} .
```

the code given is:

```
public function regicareActivitiesClusterBewegen($activityID) {
    global $activity;
    $everything = null;

    try {
        $key = 329;
        if ($activityID != -1) {

            $currentActivity = json_decode(
                                json_encode(
                                    $activity->getSpecificActivity($activityID)), true);
            $key = count($currentActivity["vrijkenmerk07"]) > 0 
                        ? array_keys($currentActivity["vrijkenmerk07"])[0] 
                        : 329;
        }

        $everything = $activity->getAllActivities(["vrijkenmerk07" => [$key]]);
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        $nothing = "<p>excuses voor het ongemak de activiteiten zijn op het moment niet beschikbaar</p>";
    }
    ob_start();

    if ($everything) {
        foreach($everything as $obj) {
            echo "
                <table style='width:100%; border-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #888888;'>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style='border-right: 3px solid #e9e9e9; padding-left: 5px; width: 66%; border-bottom: none;'>
                            <p style='color: black; font-size:16px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 600; '>" . $obj->omschrijving . "</p> 
                          <p style='color: #BD3A84; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 0px;'>" .
                        $obj->locatie->{1} .
                        $obj->locatie->{2} .
                        $obj->locatie->{3} .
                        $obj->locatie->{4} .
                        $obj->locatie->{5} .
                        $obj->locatie->{6} .
                        $obj->locatie->{7} .
                        $obj->locatie->{8} .
                        $obj->locatie->{13} .
                        $obj->locatie->{26} .
                        $obj->locatie->{29} .
                        $obj->locatie->{32} .
                        $obj->locatie->{34} .
                        $obj->locatie->{38} .
                        $obj->locatie->{40} .
                        $obj->locatie->{46} .
                        $obj->locatie->{47} .
                        $obj->locatie->{50} .
                        $obj->locatie->{51} .
                        $obj->locatie->{52} .
                        $obj->locatie->{55} .
                        $obj->locatie->{56} .
                        $obj->locatie->{57} .
                        $obj->locatie->{58} .
                        $obj->locatie->{59} .
                        "</p>
                    </td>
                    <td style='padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle; width: 17%; border-bottom: none;'>
                        <p style='margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 17px; text-align: center; color: gray;'>kosten</p>
                        <p style='font-size: 18px; color: black; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center;'>"
                        . "€". number_format($obj->prijs, 2, ',', ' ') . "</p>
                    </td>
                    <td style='padding: 0px; width: 17%; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; border-bottom: none; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background-color: #BD3A84; '>
                            <a href='http://cbwedamvolendam.nl/inschrijven/?activityID=$obj->activiteitID'> <button class='btn btn-inschrijven'>inschrijven</button> </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <br>
            </tbody>
            </table>";
        }
    } else {
        echo $nothing;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

when I var(dump) the $everything I get below.

[image]

What I expect is that the Locatie will be in ever table as below. When locatie is available show otherwise empty. This works fine with php 7.4.

[image]

Comment: Seems you are accessing an array  so use `$obj->locatie[1]` instead, read more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php Topic *Support for deprecated curly braces for offset access has been removed*

Comment: [PHP is deprecating dynamically declared properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.dynamic-properties). You'll need to see if the [property exists](https://www.php.net/property_exists) before you try to access it.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Dynamic properties are being deprecated, but that [does not affect `stdClass`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/undefined_property_error_promotion).

Comment: Fixed: add @ to the code : @$obj->locatie->{1} .